# TCP server hangs after first connection

Tags: c, networking, tcpserver

i am implementing a simple TCP echo server, which writes back whatever is written to it.i use telnet to connect to it when i first send some data to it,it is sent back(expected) but after that it hangs on i assume as nothing is sent back.

here is my code (a little modified version of example in  `man getaddrinfo`).is there any problem with how i `recv()` and `send()` below?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>


#define MAX_LISTEN_BACKLOG 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int sfd,n,s;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result;
    struct addrinfo *rp;
    struct sockaddr_storage peer_addr;
    socklen_t peer_addr_len;
    ssize_t nread;
    int addr_info_error;


    memset(&hints,0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0){
        printf("got error getaddrinfo");
    }

    for( rp = result; rp !=NULL; rp = rp->ai_next){
      sfd = socket(rp->ai_family,rp->ai_socktype,rp->ai_protocol);
      if (sfd == -1) perror("could not create socket");
      if (bind(sfd,rp->ai_addr,rp->ai_addrlen) == 0 ) break;
      close(sfd);
    }

    if (rp == NULL){
        perror("could not bind");
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    int nsfd;
    listen(sfd,100);


    for(;;){

        peer_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
        nsfd = accept(sfd,(struct sockaddr*) &peer_addr_len,&peer_addr_len);
        nread = recv(nsfd,buf,BUFFER_SIZE,0);
        if(nread == -1)
            continue;
        printf("got ...%d",nread); // this line never prints?????
        char host[NI_MAXHOST], service[NI_MAXSERV];
        s = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*) &peer_addr,
                peer_addr_len,host,NI_MAXHOST,
                service,NI_MAXSERV,NI_NUMERICSERV);

        if (s == 0) printf("recieved %s bytes from host:%s port:%s",nread,host,service);
        else printf("got %d in s",s); 
        if(send(nsfd,buf,nread,0) != nread)
            perror("error sending response");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("got ...%d",nread); // this line never prints????` :add a "\n" to the message.(and diagnotic output should go to stderr)

Comment: @wildplasser after adding `\n` i got the output but why was it not working beefore i mean `\n` adds a new line right?. also after first response nothing is sent back

Comment: @wildplasser got why `\n` is required.but any idea why it only echoes for the first time only?

Comment: 1) Because stdout is *line buffered* 2) because you  block on accept() the second time in the loop.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for the reply .but why is it that it block the second time only? also what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: i got it working by moving accept out of the loop

Comment: *correct* way: use two (nested) loops.

Comment: @wildplasser i didnt get it .a simple example will be very helpful.currently i got it working by moving accept out of loop. is it not the correct way?

Comment: regarding: `printf("got error getaddrinfo");`  error text should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest: `perror("getaddrinfo failed");`  This would be a good time to cleanup then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `if (sfd == -1) perror("could not create socket");
      if (bind(sfd,rp->ai_addr,rp->ai_addrlen) == 0 ) break;` 1) why call `break;`?  2) when `socket()` fails, do not try and `bind()` that (non existent) socket

Comment: regarding: `if (rp == NULL){
        perror("could not bind");` keep activities and error checking together with the code that indicated the error/   Also, `perror()` does not exit your program,  so (in general) should be followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `listen(sfd,100);`  the code should be checking the returned value to assure the operation was successful, not blindly stepping into the following `for()` loop

Comment: regarding: `nsfd = accept(sfd,(struct sockaddr*) &peer_addr_len,&peer_addr_len);`  1) the second parameter should be the address of the client 'struct sockaddr_in` not the address of the `socklen`  2) `accept()` can return a failure indication. so should be checking for that event.

Comment: regarding: `printf("got ...%d",nread); // this line never prints?????`  Amongst other less obvious things, the format string should end with '\n' so if it ever is executed, it will be displayed to the terminal immediately.

Comment: regarding: `int nsfd;`  the function: read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int` so the line should be: `ssize_t nsfd;`

Comment: the posted code is going back to the `accept()` statement before finishing with the current client (I.E. peer) via a recv()/send() loop until the returned value from `recv()` indicates either 0 or an error occurred.  Then close the client socket (nsfd) then go back to the `accept()` statement.

Comment: regarding: `listen(sfd,100);` indicates there could be 100 clients at a time in the wait queue, waiting for the code to service them.  Since the code is not using a `thread pool` but rather stays with an individual client until that client disconnects, any client way out on the queue could wind up waiting for a very long time.  Suggest: `listen(sfd,3); so if the queue builds up (to 3 clients waiting) then any additional clients that try to connect will get a 'busy' response

Comment: regarding: `perror("error sending response");`  the call to `send()` may result in less bytes sent than wanted.  Then the call to `send()` should be repeated with the remaining bytes, until an error occurs or all the bytes are sent.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `nread = recv(nsfd,buf,BUFFER_SIZE,0);
        if(nread == -1) continue;`  at this point in the code there is an open socket `nsfd` that needs to be passed to `close()`  Similar considerations exist for when all done with the 'proposed' recv()/send() loop

Comment: @user3629249 woow! so many mistakes i had. thanks for complete review!  :)

Answer (score -2):

[this text intended for people who cannot read the code]

- Add an extra loop after `accept()` has succeeded. This loop finishes once the connection is terminated.
- check errno after read() returns -1
- diagnostic output should go to stderr, not stdout.

---

```
for(;;){

    peer_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
    nsfd = accept(sfd,(struct sockaddr*) &peer_addr_len,&peer_addr_len);
    if (nsfd ==-1) {perror("error sending response"); break; }

    for(;;) {
            nread = recv(nsfd,buf,BUFFER_SIZE,0);
            fprintf(stderr, "got ...%d",nread);
            if(nread == -1){
                    if(errno==EAGAIN) continue;
                    else break;
                    }
            if(nread == 0) break;

            char host[NI_MAXHOST], service[NI_MAXSERV];
            s = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*) &peer_addr,
                    peer_addr_len,host,NI_MAXHOST,
                    service,NI_MAXSERV,NI_NUMERICSERV);

            if (s == 0) fprintf(stderr
                    , "received %s bytes from host:%s port:%s\n"
                    , nread,host,service);
            else fprintf(stderr, "got %d in s\n", s);

            if(send(nsfd,buf,nread,0) != nread) {
                    perror("error sending response");
                    break;
                    }

    }
    close(nsfd);
}
```

Comment: Some comments explaining what you did would be nice.